# How to transfer > 8K sensitive binary information to Azure IoT Device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

How can an IoT device which connects to an IoT Hub using the Azure IoT Hub SDK retrieve larger amounts of sensitive data which is part of the device configuration?

I know i can use Device Twins as configuration documents per Device, but those are limited to 8K in total.
I need larger amounts of data in binary format to be transfered to the device when i a device - for example - gets reset to factory defaults or somehow loses it's local storage as part of a hardware fault.

I was thinking about using a D2C method triggering a request which results in a series of C2D or direct method calls to the requesting device transmitting the information in question (basically mimiking  request/response behavior). However this feels like a workaround.

My other thought was about transmitting urls to a storage account as part of the device twin properties allowing the device to download the binary information using the Storage SDK, however given the sensitive nature of the information downloaded i can't directly expose this information to the internet using a public accessible container in Azure Storage.

So my last thought was to access a REST API which controls access to the information. However my concern is, that i break out of the secure communication channel, the IoT Hub SDK provides with it's build in communication methods and i have to secure the communication between device and the REST API using some kind of rotating secret anyway which could expose other risks along with a complicated custom implementation.

What is the suggested way of providing access to this kind of device-specific data for Azure IoT Clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do recommend to use a new feature (still in the preview) of the Azure IoT Hub such as a [Device Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-streams-overview).

You can test this new preview feature using my updated tool [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester#Appendix_A_-_Version_1.1) (see Appendix A2)

Comment: thank you very much for pointing out this option. so, as device streams seem to be initiated by the server side, to enable my scenario, i will have to send an initial D2C message to inform the server side to initiate the device stream for a client. after acceptance by the device-side, the server can carry on and send the requested sensitive information. do i understand this correctly?

Comment: you can create a state using the device twin reported properties, which will notify your cloud service for device streaming (that's a device inquiry). The service handling the device streaming process similar to the device direct invoking a method. During this handshaking both ends switching to the secured web socket communication. Once this communication is done, the device twin state can be updated.

Comment: Ok, thank you! so conceptionally it's similar to sending a request from the device to the cloud (either Device Twin Reported Property or D2C Message) and sending multiple direct method calls to the device in question but it's more efficient and the client could use the web socket connection to send additional requests, right?

Comment: There is only one Request/Response call between the backend service and the device. The service sends your custom application payload with few headers such as **url, auth-token, ip-address** (for wss communication) and the device responded with an app payload and returning back those headers with adding one more such as  *iothub-streaming-is-accepted:True*.